# Assigning GPUs to HyperV2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, hyper-v-server-2012, remote-desktop

I have followed the instructions provided by TechNet to setup HyperV 2012 (Windows Server 2012 Std) to assign GPUs within the HyperV settings:  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16652.remotefx-vgpu-setup-and-configuration-guide-for-windows-server-2012.aspx?PageIndex=2&wa=wsignin1.0&CommentPosted=true

However, even though I have verified the requirements, HyperV 2012 still gives me the following error with in the HyperV Settings:  None of the physical graphics processing units (GPUs) on this computer support RemoteFX.

I have an NVidia NVS 300 installed in the server with the latest driver from the NVidia website.  This card is listed on as an approved graphics adapter on the Windows catalog site:  http://www.windowsservercatalog.com/item.aspx?idItem=fb3893a3-d86e-da14-dc34-ddd21ca2ab9e&bCatID=1564

I don't understand why I would be getting this error.  Any ideas?

Comment: The DX feature level bit me.  The NVS 300 only has a DX feature level of 10.  Server 2012 requires a feature level 11 for RemoteFX.  The NVS 310 has the new DX11 feature set.  Solved.